# Error al consultar dentro de método de controlador con LINQ: The function evaluation requiries all threads to run

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, spring-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Solicito de su apoyo en este detalle que no logro entender.

Estoy trabajando con MVC C# / SQL Server 2014 / VS 2019 / LINQ... y tengo un método para validara login, hasta hace unos momentos no tenia problema ahí, pero de la nada por unos cambios que hice en el mismo método en solo los If para llegar a esa parte... me empezó a notificar este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Depurando me doy cuenta que envía el error desde que se consulta en cat_usuario, pero la variable -usuario- se llena con datos, y se convalida en los if y switch que le preceden. Ahora bien al llegar y consultar la tabla cat_usuario_aplicacion misma notificación de error "The function evaluation requiries all threads to run", pero la variable -existeAplicacion- se vuelve llenar con datos, y al momento de llegar y consutar la tabla cat_usuario_permisos la variable existePermisoAppRol se queda en null.

Les reitero no me daba problema antes y esas tablas estar relacionadas por Id, y solo de pruea tengo 2 usuarios que tienen los datos respectivamente en las tablas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 TL;DR: Edita la pregunta, coloca código en lugar de pantallazos + Incluye tus clases + la estructura de la base de datos y todo aquello que sea necesario para reproducir tu escenario. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, lo tomare en cuenta a la hora de formular futuras preguntas. La verdad nosotros los novatos nos queremos comunicar de tal forma que sea claro lo que tenemos y se nos remueva e ilustre en la mayoría de las veces soluciones a trabas que nos enfrentamos.

Comment: Mientras tanto me doy cuenta que la tabla tiene relación con otras tablas, y cuando consulto(LINQ) me muestra las advertencias relacionadas con las otras tablas con las que tiene relación; ya sea por que no encuentra información relacionada o bien por que debo armar la consulta incluyendo las tablas relacionadas... tal ves este mal en esta teoría, pero sigo verificando ya que por lo general siempre utilizo SP para consultar/insertar/actualizar información y muy poco LINQ para hacer las operaciones directas... pero si alguien me puede contribuir con alguna falla que vea, muy agradecido...

Comment: Soy daltonico y no puedo diferenciar partes del codigo en tus imagenes, puedes [edit] la pregunta con lo sugerido por @fredyfx